# python logger KeyError 'messages'

Tags: python, logging, keyerror

Below code is my logger settings

```
# generate log
logger = logging.getLogger()

# log level
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#log formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(messages)s')

# log to console
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

#log to file
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('my.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

and when I try to print log, I got below error

```
logger.info('hi')
```

KeyError: 'messages'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'messages'
Message: 'hi'
Arguments: ()

Does this error occurs because I am trying to output logs in jupyter notebook?
If not, please help me to print normal logs..

Comment: You have a typo in your format - `logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(messages)s')` should be `logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')`. Notice it's called `message` and not `messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @wkl

Reference to @wkl 's comment

> You have a typo in your format - logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(messages)s') should be logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'). Notice it's called message and not messages